# typescript: how to create a Type which can convert a string to uppercase

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I want to create a Type in typescript which can convert a string to uppercase:

```
type _Upper<T> = ...

_Upper<'abc'> // 'ABC'
```

can anyone tell me this?

Comment: You mean this? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#intrinsic-string-manipulation-types

Comment: @Calculuswhiz is right; you don't have to write this type, it already exists as `Uppercase<T>`.  If that intrinsic type didn't exist you could presumably build a template literal parser type that converts some hardcoded alphabet to uppercase, but it would probably be prohibitively expensive to write one that worked for all of Unicode. [Observe this](https://tsplay.dev/W4y2aw).   Does that answer work for you or are we missing something?

Comment: hi Calculuswhiz: you are right, however I want to write a Type UpperCase BY MYSELF. The link provided by @jcalz help me a lot, but is that the most suitable method?

Comment: @fawinell I don't know how to answer if it's "the most suitable method" unless you can articulate *why* do you want to write it yourself instead of using the native `Uppercase<T>`.  What are your requirements?  Is this just a thought experiment for fun?  Or do you have some kind of use case?

Comment: hi @jcalz: thanks for your advice, yes it's just a thought experiment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *correct* way to do this is to just use [the existing `Uppercase<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#uppercasestringtype).  This is an *`intrinsic`* type as introduced in [microsoft/TypeScript#40580](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40580), which means that it is implemented in the compiler itself; you can look at [`checker.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/0fcd86150e22648147c4a35614a5f80492b25ac3/src/compiler/checker.ts?raw=true) at approximately line 15,085:

```
case IntrinsicTypeKind.Uppercase: return str.toUpperCase()
```

That means you could define your custom `_Upper<T>` type like this:

```
type _Upper<T extends string> = Uppercase<T>;
```

Yes, that's a trivial definition.  But it has the advantage of being simple to define and working according to the [Unicode standard case mapping](https://unicode.org/faq/casemap_charprop.html#casemap) algorithm:

```
type ABC = _Upper<'abc'>
// type ABC = "ABC"

type Sentence = _Upper<"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.">;
// type Sentence = "THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG."

type Хорошо = Uppercase<"я не знаю">;
// type Хорошо = "Я НЕ ЗНАЮ"
```

---

If you don't want to use `Uppercase<T>`, you can use recursive [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) to implement something yourself.  But note that to do so *accurately* requires that you keep a mapping of all Unicode characters which need to be changed when converted to upper case.  At the very least that would be a fairly large mapping (over 2,000 characters I think).

If all you care about are the 26 characters of the Latin alphabet, then you can write it like this:

```
interface Uppers {
  a: "A", b: "B", c: "C", d: "D", e: "E", f: "F", g: "G", 
  h: "H", i: "I", j: "J", k: "K", l: "L", m: "M",
  n: "N", o: "O", p: "P", q: "Q", r: "R", s: "S", t: "T", 
  u: "U", v: "V", w: "W", x: "X", y: "Y", z: "Z"
}

type _Upper<T extends string, A extends string = ""> =
  T extends `${infer F}${infer R}` ?
  _Upper<R, `${A}${F extends keyof Uppers ? Uppers[F] : F}`> : A;
```

So `Uppers` is the mapping type from lowercase (keys) to uppercase (values).  The `_Upper<T>` type parses the string `T` character-by-character. If the character `F` is lowercase (`F extends keyof Uppers`) then it converts it to uppercase (`Uppers[F]`), otherwise it leaves it alone (`F`).  It's a [tail-recursive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#tail-recursion-elimination-on-conditional-types) definition (using the `A` type parameter as an accumulator) so in TypeScript 4.5 and above, this will work for quite long string literals.

Let's test it:

```
type ABC = _Upper<'abc'>
// type ABC = "ABC"

type Sentence = _Upper<"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.">;
// type Sentence = "THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG."

type Плохо = _Upper<"я не знаю">;
// type Плохо = "я не знаю" // oops
```

Well, the first two are good.

But the last one doesn't work; the lowercase Cyrillic string is unaffected.  This could be fixed, if necessary, by augmenting the `Uppers` type with the Cyrillic alphabet.  The basic algorithm here, parsing the string and looking up each character in a mapping, is probably the best we can do.  Well, the *best* would be to use the built-in `Uppercase<T>`. But if `Uppercase<T>` didn't exist, then a recursive conditional template literal type like this would be reasonable.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBhA9gJwxeAXJA3gLABQSSuAnjMgPoCqMNGAPACpIQAeuEwAJlCRRcGAJbAA5gD4kAXiSNm8EFAjtpAblKlyVGkgCCAIRTykDJhFYByEACN4N6bqQB6NxWrITZhQCJffx0yLwMAZT5eYERzS2YWfzYAC2QARwBXMXgAayR7DDQAd2AkADM0LiQAKwywGCE0ADdrClSkABsQAC9KJH40SQA6fy1XDzDkSOBo2IC2AAkAUSQARXoASRQAaSRjACUAeQB1ADkkADFDgA0kACl6AFkABXCkQ4A1Jf2kRZWAGUMAC0AJpIAAihwA4iMQnpvEhAKQggD4QQACIMjABIgyPMSmsKjUiUA8iBIQC8IIBWECQgHYQEmABhBAHIgo20oQm+mQKPRWPM-kA9CBIQC4IIBUECQgHQQPmABBBAHQgwRIAF8QqBILAEFNMLhDmVCK4JLwMGVlYorBghMRQuQQAAuJCBfwAGnylv8xltSHgDpQzv4DvBzogDqWzrKDouzskDqhzuSDoWzrEDo2zuqDruzpyDu2zo6Dv+zrADsettc5GADtOzrQDsOzpgDuezrSDtWzowDv2zqgDvCztwDrYzoyDvozqaDo+zqKDuOzq4DuuzsoDpBzu6DqB0vIcpIrlZFlxrA43GigmEogkkjthk4PD4R5E4ikXNG8kLv0vh6EAAMACQECRlVoXGVv1-Vp9hld8kAAfmfeJrBYfY7S-AhDEAggLlfa8hByCBKDQDVdyECCDWYKAAG0LgAXSQS0APfWRLUMJk4UmIxTDiXcWDsRxnHGTxt18LkgiY7dplmZAFBg1gknaTJsjyApilKCoqlqepGhaDA2mQLpen6QYRjGZleIRES+DmK0-jWTYdj2I4zkuG57ieV53i+H4LMBUEIWhWFN1CbdAHwQQBuEGRQBREGxcT2P8YlySpWkGQM8gWQRILQvCq1oopal6WlUgZSAA)